# Sinch Voice Callback REST API - Using PHP as Callback URL for conference calls

Tags: php, rest, sinch

I'm trying to use the Sinch Voice Callback REST API to create an application to allow people to join a conference call making app-to-app calls from a browser. I also want to use a PHP backend.

I understand from this (https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/voice-callback-api.html) that my application's Callback URL needs to respond to an 'ICE' event from Sinch first. Here is what the 'ICE' event looks like https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/voice-callback-api.html#incomingcalleventcallback.

I would then need to respond to this 'ICE' with the 'connectConf' action. (https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/voice-callback-api.html#connectconfaction)

When the 'ACE" event comes I would then only need to respond with the action "continue". Like this resource explains (https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/voice-callback-api.html#answeredcalleventcallback)

I have minor experience with PHP but I feel I may be oversimplifying what Sinch is expecting in response from my Callback URL since I can't get it to work. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far in my Callback URL's file.

```
<?php
    $event = $_POST['event'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];

    if ( $event === 'ice' ){
        $response = '{
            "name" : "connectConf",
            "conferenceId" : "conftest14",
            "moh" : "ring"
        }';
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else if ( $event === 'ace' ){
        $response = '{
                "action":
                {
                    "name" : "continue"
                }
            }';
        echo json_encode($response);
    };
?>
```

Comment: In ice you need to have action: and then the connectConf as the action

Comment: Thanks cjensen. I fixed that but am still unable to connect to the conference call

Comment: @cjensen I have made some more changes that still haven't proven to work. Do you see anything else I'm doing wrong?
      

`<?php  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
    $event = $_POST['event'];  
    $conferenceId = $_POST['to']['endpoint'];  
    if ( $event === 'ice' ){  
        $response = '{  
            "action":  
            {  
                "name" : "connectConf",  
                "conferenceId" : "'+$conferenceId+'"  
            }  
        }';  
        echo json_encode($response);  
    }  
?>  `

Answer (score 0):

In ice you need to have action: and then the connectConf as the action

```
{
    "action":
    {
        "name" : "connectConf",
        "conferenceId" : "conftest14"
    }
}
```